# Unable to add audio clip in audio source in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, fmod

I have added audio source component in Unity Scene but I am unable to add audio clip in it. It is throwing the following error:

```
Errors during import of AudioClip Assets/sound1.ogg:
FSBTool ERROR: The format of the source file is invalid, see output for details.
FSBTool ERROR: Internal error from FMOD sub-system.

UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I am using Unity version 2019.3.14f1. I have tried different sound source formats (mp3 and wav) but it is trowing the same error. How to resolve this?

Comment: Is your file a **`Vorbis`** codec ogg ? Other [OGG Codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#Ogg_codecs) are not supported (See [Supported formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html)) In general I'ld suggest using `WAV` or `MP3` where possible

Comment: @derHugo I have also tried mp3 and wav format as well but they are throwing the same error.

Comment: What happens if you import the audio file into a fresh Unity project, does it produce the same error? Also how big is your audio file, what happens if you use a smaller file? There used to be issues in the past with FMOD and large audio files. Which FMOD version are you using?

Comment: @Remy It is giving the same error in fresh file and with smaller files. Do I have to explicitly install the fmod or is it comes automatically installed with unity?

Comment: @shivank01 AFAIK FMOD isn't shipped with Unity, they have unity integration and saw `Internal error from FMOD sub-system.` so I assumed you were using it. I don't know why it would try to call an FMOD system if you're not using it.. Does this happen with all your audio files, or just some? If you got a file that does work try inspecting its properties to see if there are any differences. If you don't have any working files try downloading one of Unity's example projects and see if audio works in there (if the example projects work it excludes Unity being corrupted)

Comment: @Remy It is not working for any of the sound files. Okay, I'll try with some Unity's example project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to work with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) when working with media formats.
ffmpeg is available for linux and windows.
A simple command to check a file is

```
ffprobe file.ogg
```

You can also do extended checks including conversion to fix the file.
There are prenty of methods. Just search for "ffmpeg integrity check"

If you are lazy as myself i would simply convert it to a wav file and back to ogg again.

```
ffmpeg -i file.ogg file.wav
ffmpeg -i file.wav file.ogg
```

Answer (score 0):

For others, who might stumble upon this:

Working solution for me was to open the file with audacity, then export it as .ogg

Answer (score 0):

This problem resurfaced in some of 2022.2.X, this time it is Unity own regression bug as reported here:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/fsbtool-error-internal-error-from-fmod-sub-system-messages-are-thrown-when-importing-ogg-files

- In my instance, it happened to all ogg files, which they were fine before upgrading (was using 2022.1.13)
- Note that this is error from Unity's internal audio engine, no any explicit FMOD audio package is installed.
- The workaround is to downgrade, nearest 2022 is 2022.1.24 (at the time of writing).
- Or to wait for future version as written in issuetracker page.

Edit:

Comment: Sill happening on 2022.3.20f1

Answer (score -1):

import a video as audio is imported with it

if you dont put the video inside the ui panal you should not see the video but keep the music

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).